# iOS 7: Multipeer Connectivity Framework - load testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I was wondering, if anybody has run some heavier load / performance tests using the new Multipeer Connectivity Framework (from iOS7 SDK)?

I have to connect up to 100 devices using the MC Framework (the data packets will be relatively small), but I have no idea whether this will be feasible at all.

Comment: Are you aware that an MCSession is limited to 8 peers?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the network connection peers will be using to connect to the signal source, you are limited either by:

1. [Wi-Fi interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Interference). For example, if peers will connect with each other by using 40-50 Wi-Fi sources (peer is a source and another peer is a receiver), then because all Wi-Fi networks will use the same frequency, peers won't be able to connect (or there'll be huge packet loss or other connectivity issues)
2. [Implementation of Bluetooth LE in iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy#Technical_details). Bluetooth 4.0 is very new technology, but as you can see in [2013' WWDC Sessions](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) ("Core Bluetooth" and "Nearby Networking with Multipeer Connectivity" sessions) Apple engineers have tested Bluetooth LE well enough in order to advertise it as a solution for multiple low-ranged networks that are close to each other.

P.S. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/192905/whats-the-maximum-number-of-wifi-connections-for-a-single-wifi-router) you can find a shared experience with a similar situation.

Comment: But let say we have an environment, where only 1 WLAN is present at time (accessible via 1+ access points) - and not all the devices do not have to be connected with each other (i.e. there will be a devices acting like a server and other are more like clients).

Comment: @iosappdeveloper87 the only limitation you'll have is a single access point for 100 devices. You'll have to use several access points in order to support this number of devices. Otherwise router will not be able to handle this number of connections. Theoretically 1 access point can handle 255 connected devices, but in most cases simple home WLAN routers, for example, can handle maximum 15 connected devices.

Comment: I think you mean Bluetooth LE (low energy) not LTE (the 4G cellular technology)